# Octave: Not all numerical integrations are created equal

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-integration

I wrote a script to compare the answers between integrating an equation exactly, summing it, and using various built-in numerical integration functions.

Here is my program:

```
xmin = -2*pi;
xmax = -xmin;
dx = 0.01;
x = [xmin:dx:xmax];
f = sin(x);
fstar = conj(f);

y = fstar.*f; %for the sum
fy = @(x) y;

fsum1 = sum(y.*dx); %approximation by treating integral as a sum

%definite integral (specific to int(sin^2(x)))
fsum2 = 0.5.*(xmax - sin(xmax).*cos(xmax) - xmin + sin(xmin).*cos(xmin)); 

%numerical integrations:
fsum3 = quad(fy,xmin,xmax);
fsum4 = quadv(fy,xmin,xmax);
fsum5 = quadl(fy,xmin,xmax);
fsum6 = quadgk(fy,xmin,xmax);
fsum7 = quadcc(fy,xmin,xmax);
```

Everything runs fine until it hangs on `fsum4`. Well, I should say that `fsum1` and `fsum2` work. However, `fsum3 = 7.53812e-031` (wrong) and `fsum4 =` a matrix the same size as `x`. When I plot `fsum4` vs. `x` I get a (sin(x))^2 function with an amplitude of a little over 12.

I've gotten the quad integration function to work before, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The main problem is your anonymous function. It has no dependence on its argument. Try `fy = @(x)(conj(sin(x)) .* sin(x));`?

Comment: Yes, right now y is just an array of numbers. fy just returns that full array of numbers no matter what you put in for x.

Comment: Quad will expect a single valued function. fy should return a single value given a single value. For the others fy has to be able to accept a vector of inputs and return a same sized vector of outputs.